# Como funciona a sincronização de texto do Google Docs no Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive-api

Então, eu não consegui encontrar essa informação, mas estou curioso para saber como que funciona a sincronização em tempo real dos documentos de texto no Google Drive.

A questão é que duas pessoas podem editar o arquivo ao mesmo tempo, com as alterações aparecendo para as duas praticamente instantaneamente.

Eu realmente quero saber como isso funciona pra ver onde eu posso implementar algo parecido, aceito links com a explicação sobre isso também.

Quero saber, como funciona essa sincronização em que os dois podem ver ao mesmo tempo o que é alterado? Que linguagem eles usam para fazer isso? Que banco eles usam? Que magia negra é essa?

Comment: A teoria não é complicada: pega o que foi modificado, envia para a outra pessoa com o arquivo aberto, e atualiza a versão dela. Nada de especial no meio, só Javascript, websocket. Provavelmente nem banco de dados tem (ou pelo menos é possível fazer sem). Não tem magia negra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A teoria não é complicada: pega o que foi modificado, envia para a outra pessoa com o arquivo aberto, e atualiza a versão dela. Nada de especial no meio, só Javascript, [websocket](http://www.html5rocks.com/pt/tutorials/websockets/basics/). Provavelmente nem banco de dados tem (ou pelo menos é possível fazer sem). Não tem magia negra, muito menos algo especial.

Na verdade, a implementação deste recurso é bastante direta, sendo a latência (minimizada com websocket), problemas de conexão e os conflitos os maiores inimigos.

A parte mais complicada é unir as alterações de uma pessoa com a da outra quando estas alterar o mesmo local ou propriedade. Neste caso, acredito que ele destaque que houve informações conflitantes e deixe o usuário resolver.

Este comportamento de conflito é diferente do dos controles de versões (git, svn, hg), que tentam primeiro resolver o conflito (usando 3-way-merge, por exemplo) e só se não for possível, pede para o usuário resolver na mão.